# Why does multiplying by dt work and is there a more elegant way of writing this?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I know multiplying by d*t* will get me to where I need to go, but why does it work? Is there a way of writing that isn't just a product with d*t*? I read about how it becomes an intergration by substitution afterwards which is why it works, but at its core, what is happening?

[image]

Comment: There’s a technical answer concerning [differential forms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), where you treat the $dt$ part as an equality of 1-forms, but personally I think it’s easier to just put/imagine an integral sign at the front of that line. The justification is the same either way: if two functions of time are equal, then their integrals over time are equal (up to a constant, if they’re indefinite).

Comment: Please use MathJax next time. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @DavidK  Sorry for the mix-up, I was actually using LaTeX but I'll try your suggestion next time thanks!

Comment: It’s good that you know LaTeX so well. Then MathJax will be easy to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in the presented working. We should see:

> $$\int v_1\frac{\mathrm{d}v_1}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int v_1\,\mathrm{d}v_1$$(Correct, up to figuring out the correct bounds) rather than the incorrect: $$\int v_1\frac{\mathrm{d}v_1}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t\overset{?}{=}\int v_1\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Usually when people "multiply" by $\mathrm{d}t$ they do something like this: $\frac{\mathrm{d}v_1}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{d}v_1$ and then integrate. In your post, the text authors instead wrote: "if $a=b$ then $a\,\mathrm{d}t=b\,\mathrm{d}t$" and then integrated both sides.

*Although multiplying by the 'infinitesimal' or the 'differential' is a little sketchy and needs care to make precise*, **you don't need to do that at all**. Just go straight from: "$a=b$" to "$\int a\,\mathrm{d}t=\int b\,\mathrm{d}t$" which is perfectly rigorous; there is nothing mysterious here. The intermediate step of $a\,\mathrm{d}t=b\,\mathrm{d}t$ is ... superfluous, and clearly runs the risk of being confusing.

In these situations, I think it's good to think of $\int(-)\,\mathrm{d}t$ as one operator, rather than think of $\int$ and $\,\mathrm{d}t$ as separate entities.

Comment: This is so much clearer, thank you! Then, would be just integration by substitution, with u=v_1 and du=v'dt ?

Comment: @EmmannuelleMercier Exactly!

Comment: @DavidK if you inspect the edit history, you’ll see the original image that $\int v_1\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: I see. I had assumed that we were looking at a screenshot of some electronic teaching materials, but apparently this was OP's own writing instead.